# HTML <template> on Edge (version ≥13)

Tags: javascript, html, templates, microsoft-edge, clonenode

I need to decide between the use of `<template>` or just constructing a highly nested element in Javascript using `documentFragment`. Using `<template>` would be at lot cleaner, but Edge support is critical and `caniuse.com` seems to indicate there's no support for version 12 and only partial support for version 13-14:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=template

> 1. Does not support Document.importNode on templates, nested templates or elements that contain templates.
> 2. Does not support Node.cloneNode on templates, nested templates or elements that contain templates.

The issue with this is that I can't test with Edge (not running Windows 10 nor do I have access to a browser testing suite) and I also can't find anything online about it, on MDN or in Microsoft documentation. Not being able to clone the template into the document pretty much means the standard way of using `<template>` goes out the window, which doesn't make sense to me because that seems to be the whole point of `<template>`.

The only place that claims this is `caniuse.com` but I've learned to trust it and it makes me uncertain about what approach to use. Chances are I'll just use `documentFragment` to be safe, but I'm wondering if this is an error on `caniuse.com` or if there is another sensible way of using `<template>` that is obvious and I'm missing it.

Comment: I know it is late but I will post my answer anyways. I didn't want to put this 'I know it is late' comment into the answer itself.

Comment: From https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/3323 it seems caniuse's warning really is misleading.

Comment: @matthecat I guess but it seems to be a 2yr old issue though, unless I'm missing something. Thanks for mentioning it here even if it is though.

Comment: Well sorry I found your question then.

Comment: @matthecat I hope it's clear not disrespect was intended...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following test document demonstrates that `importNode` and `cloneNode` appear to work correctly with `template` in Edge, at least for version 15 and up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<title>&lt;template&gt; testing</title>

<div id="wrapper">
    <template id="outer">lol<template id="inner">wut</template></template>
</div>

<script>
    var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper').cloneNode(true);
    var outer = wrapper.querySelector('#outer');
    var clone = outer.cloneNode(true);
    var inner = document.importNode(clone.content.lastChild, true);
    var content = document.importNode(inner.content, true);
    document.body.appendChild(content);
</script>
```

For what it's worth, you typically wouldn't "clone the template into the document" as mentioned in your question, but rather clone the template's *contents* into the document:

```
let template = document.querySelector('template');
document.body.append(document.importNode(template.content, true));
```

Comment: Thanks. I did figure out that it works even back then. I made a test page and used browserscope or something. Was a pretty intense time and I neglected to post my findings.

Comment: To be clear: all this is related to Edge from version 13 up; if one has to support Edge in general, you can't use the `template` tag as the version 12 does not support it, [as caniuse.com reports](https://caniuse.com/?search=template). I'll update the question title so it's more explicit.