# not so sure how to declare a variable that will use in nodeJS and rendering in HTML/template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, variable-declaration, edge.js

I'm using nodejs and Edge template to render dynamic data in HTMl elements , fed up with different solution but nothing seems working for me. I have used #App.locals, to declare the variable but getting function anonymous. So stick to original i want to return some data in x variable. I would appreciate your response , thank you.

code snippet :
Example 1

```
const app =require(express)
const edge = require('edge.js')
app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
edge.global('id', req.session.userId)
next()
});
```

> > here i'm getting an error as global is not a function

no luck so i run to different code

Example 2 :

```
const app =require(express)
var xvariable = {
id:"1"
}
app.use('*', (res, req, next) => {
app.locals = xvariable

console.log(id)  // expecting output as 1 but  getting function[asynchronous]

next()
});
```

Comment: This looks like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/); please tell us what your goal is here. Inserting a variable into an express view?

Comment: Just Figure out , thanks to this post >>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48400009/html-template-on-edge

app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
   app.locals.xvariable =  req.session.userId
    next();
  
}); // > adding login page for Guest

Comment: Great, in that case feel free to delete this question